# Intersection and summation of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Columm spaces of matrices are:

$$C(A)=span\{\begin{pmatrix}
       1 \\
       0 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{pmatrix} ,\begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix} ,\begin{pmatrix}
        0\\
        1 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}\},C(B)=span\{\begin{pmatrix}
       1 \\
       2 \\
        3 \\
        4 \\
        \end{pmatrix} ,\begin{pmatrix}
        4 \\
        3 \\
        2 \\
        1 \\
        \end{pmatrix} \} $$

Null spaces of matrices are:

$$N(A)=span\{\begin{pmatrix}
       -1 \\
       1 \\
        -1 \\
        1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}, N(B)=span\{\begin{pmatrix}
      -2 \\
       0 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix} ,\begin{pmatrix}
       -3 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{pmatrix} \} 
$$

How can I find $C(A)\cap C(B),C(A)+C(B)$

For null spaces $N(A)\cap N(B),N(A)+N(B)$ ?

**My solution :**

$$C(A)+C(B)=span\{\begin{pmatrix}
       1 \\
       0 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{pmatrix} ,\begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix} ,\begin{pmatrix}
        0\\
        1 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
       \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
       1 \\
       2 \\
        3 \\
        4 \\
        \end{pmatrix} ,\begin{pmatrix}
        4 \\
        3 \\
        2 \\
        1 \\
        \end{pmatrix} \}$$
Will it be same for $N(A)+N(B)$?

How it will be with $C(A)\cap C(B),N(A) \cap N(B)$ ?

Can you give me any tips?
Thanks for help!

**EDIT**

I think I got it. When you want to find $C(A)+C(B)$ (basically summation of any subspaces), you create matrix with these subspace and you need to find columm space of this summation. If  you want intersection, you need to find nullspace of matrix.

Comment: Yes, the sum of two spans is the span of the union of the generating vectors.

Comment: @Berci Thanks, so for nullspaces it will be the same, now I am thinking about intersection ...

Comment: By the dimension formula you should know the dimension of the intersection, then you need to find that many linearly independent elements in the intersection.

Comment: @Berci does it mean that I will take eg C(A)= C(B) , and I will find solution ?

Comment: @Berci I think I got it. Please read EDIT section. Thank you.